# How to find a corresponding record in a second collection?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Collection A format:

```
{_id:'123123435', order_id:'128390183', number:10}
```

Collection B format:

```
{_id:'1979798', 'order_id':'128390183', remind_number:5}
```

If I know one document of B, like `b_doc`, now I can get the corresponding  `B.document`?

mongo(javascript grammar):

```
a_doc = db.A.findOne({order_id: b_doc.order_id})
```

But now, I meet a tricky problem: I want to just write a query command that can gets the following effect:

```
db.A.find({remind_numer:{$gt: corresponding.b_doc.number} })
```

Answer (score 1):

Here could be one solution through [`aggregation`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/), join `orderA` and `orderB` with same order_id through `$lookup`, and put the related `orderB` document to `order` field. Then deconstructs this array field `order` through `$unwind`, compare the `remind_number` and `number` in the `$project` stage. Then filter the compare result above through `$match` which `remind_number` larger than `number`.

```
> db.orderA.aggregate([
         // combine orderA and orderB though `order_id`
         {$lookup: {
              from: 'orderB', 
              localField: 'order_id', 
              foreignField: 'order_id', 
              as: 'order'}}, 
         // unwind the `order` array
         {$unwind: '$order'}, 
         // compare the `remind_number` and `number`
         {$project: { 'order_id':1, 
                      number: 1, 
                      order: 1, 
                      cmpvalue: {$cmp: ['$order.remind_number', '$number']}}}, 
         // filter the order which `remind_number` greater then `number`
         {$match: {cmpvalue: {$gt: 0}}},
         // only include the fields of orderA
         {$project: {order_id: 1, number: 1, }}
  ]);
```